# List elements without indentation

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

I am using the `enumitem` package to tweak the `enumerate` environment. I would like to have all the items in different levels aligned in the left margin. I tried with different parameters of the package unsuccesfully.
I also need to align the sentences in the items.

```
a.     iten1
b.     item2
b.1.   item3
c.     item 4
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please expand your question? It's not quite clear what you mean by "align the sentences in the items".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that typesets the labels in the margin:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{align=left,leftmargin=0pt,labelsep=0pt,labelwidth=3em}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label*=\arabic*.}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Second-first
  \end{enumerate}
\item Third
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Addding `itemindent=3em` to the example above will make the labels left-aligned at the left margin:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{align=left,leftmargin=0pt,labelsep=0pt,labelwidth=3em,itemindent=3em}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label*=\arabic*.}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Second-first
  \end{enumerate}
\item Third
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]